# HTML/JavaScript: How to detect a blank submission Form?

Tags: javascript, html

below is a simple form requesting user feedback.

Using HTML and/or JavaScript, how do you create an alert box that pops up whenever it detects the the entire Form or a portion of the Form is blank? E.g. whenever the user clicks to submit a blank/incomplete form, alert box: "You forgot to fill out Name/Email/Comments".

Thanks lot.

```
    <div>
        <form method="post" enctype="text/plain" action="MAILTO:name@example.com">
        Your Name<br>
        <input type="text" size="40" name="name">
        <br><br>
        Email Address<br>
        <input type="text" size="40" name="email">
        <br><br>
        Any Comments or Questions?<br>
        <textarea name="comments" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        <br><br>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're right about using JavaScript.
<script>
function notEmpty()
{
var myTextField = document.getElementById("name");
if (myTextField1.value == "")
alert("Please fill in your name!")
}
</script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use HTML5 `required` attribute for this

```
<div>
    <form method="post" enctype="text/plain" action="MAILTO:name@example.com">
    Your Name<br>
    <input type="text" size="40" name="name" required>
    <br><br>
    Email Address<br>
    <input type="text" size="40" name="email" required>
    <br><br>
    Any Comments or Questions?<br>
    <textarea name="comments" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    <br><br>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Expand your Form Tag

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();" method="post" enctype="text/plain" action="MAILTO:name@example.com">
```

Basic info here: The `validate()` method is called whenever you try to submit the form. The boolean return of the `validate()` function decides if the form is sumbmitted or not.

For convenience, add `id` attributes to all fields. Example:

```
<input type="text" size="40" name="email" id="email">
```

## The `validate()` method

This is the heart of your form test.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate()
    {
        var messages = new Array();
        if (document.getElementById('email').value.length == 0)
        {
            messages.push('E-Mail missing');
        }
        if (document.getElementById('name').value.length == 0)
        {
            messages.push('Name missing');
        }
        if (0 == messages.length)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Do something with the messages array
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Have fun.

Comment: It needs to be `onsubmit="return validate();"`

Answer (score 0):

If you know javascript it's a piece of cake.If not, you can use [this](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/).